# Is Python multiprocessing Pool thread safe?

Tags: python, django

I have Django project. If I make package variable that contains **Pool()** object, and will try to use that Pool from Django views (which run in parallel way), will be this way thread safe? Are there any others ways to do it?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
general_executor_pool = Pool()
```

Answer (score 7):

I found this question via Google as I'm asking the same question. Anecdotally I can say NO it is not, because I recently debugged a piece of software that suffered from race conditions. Here's how it went:

1. A master process ran in a loop and spawned a multiprocessing pool in a new thread eery 3 minutes with a list of ~1000 accounts to be acted on
2. The thread called multiprocessing.Pool(max_proccesses=32), pool.map(func, accounts). This would open 32 processes, and one by one apply each account to an available process.
3. Unbeknownst to the original author, this process took far longer to complete than 3 minutes. So what happened the next time a thread was spawned to create a multiprocessing pool? Did it spawn 32 new processes for a total of 64? No, in practice it did not. Instead my results were scrambled and showed indication that multiple threads were acting on my data in a non-deterministic way.

I'd love to trace through the multiprocessing module to see if it is un-thread-safe by design, or get an answer from someone in the know. Anecdotally, at least, I have witnessed first hand that it is not.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I had to check this and it seems that multiprocessing.pool.Pool **is indeed thread-safe.**
The following code does not trigger an AssertionError (tested with Python 3.6.9) :

```
import random
import time
import multiprocessing.pool
from threading import Thread

pool = multiprocessing.pool.Pool()

def return_value(value):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return value
count = 100
def call_return_value():
    counter_start = random.randint(0, 100)
    result = list(range(counter_start, counter_start + count))
    pool_result = pool.imap_unordered(return_value, range(counter_start, counter_start + count), chunksize=1)
    pool_result = list(pool_result)
    assert set(pool_result) == set(result)
tl = [Thread(target=call_return_value) for _ in range(24)]
for t in tl:
    t.start()
```

Basically, this code starts a Process Pool, and lauches 24 threads calling the `return_value` function via this pool. This functions returns the value after waiting for a random delay (between 0 and 1s).

Of course, pool_result is not ordered anymore, but it contains the correct set of elements, and this is true for all threads : values do not get mixed.